# sock failed (2: No such file or directory) Django 1.8, Nginx, Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I am confused by 502 error at my django project. As far as I understand nginx fails to pass to gunicorn, but I am not sure. I followed all steps from here very accurately https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/glboy
ExecStart=/home/root/glboy/denv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/root/glboy/closer.sock closer.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/closer` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 46.101.192.66;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/glboy/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/root/glboy/closer.sock;
    }
}
```

also found tutorial where `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` was also edited, tried as well despite I do not fully understand the purpose :

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 46.101.192.66;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/glboy/static;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

In nginx error log absence of socket is reported

```
/home/root/glboy/closer.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I just copied the path how should it be according to instruction, but if it's wrong what path is right or what is wrong otherwise?

Comment: it can work with different privilages and it can't have access to `/home/root`. Some web servers runs as user `wwwdata` so hackers have no access to `root` privillages.

Comment: @furas I tried 'sudo chown -R  root ~' is it correct? Didn't work

Comment: you set `root` as owner but server mostly doesn't run as `root` and it doesn't have access to `root` folders (so hackers can't use bugs in server to get access as root to all data on server).